# Занять и одолжить: есть ли разница?

Tags: значение-слов

По идее, занимаешь кому-то, а одалживаешь у кого-то. Но часто говорят: "Займи мне денег". Правильно ли это, или занимать можно действительно только у кого-то?

Answer (score 8):

ЗАНИМА́ТЬ1, занимаю, занимаешь, несовер. (к занять1), что и без доп. 1. Брать взаймы. Денег не хватает: приходится постоянно занимать. Он у многих занимал деньги. **2. кому-чему. Давать кому-нибудь взаймы (обл., неправ.).**
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ушакова

Таким образом, выражение ЗАЙМИ МНЕ ДЕНЕГ неправильное.

Comment: Но такое распространенное!!!

Comment: >выражение ЗАЙМИ МНЕ ДЕНЕГ неправильное.   
  
С момента писания словаря Ушаковым много воды утекло.   
Правильным оно, имхо, не стало, но из "обл." явно превратилось в повсеместное.

Comment: Тем не менее, до тех пор, пока значение *дать в долг* для слова *занять* не станет языковой нормой, оно остается ошибочным несмотря на распространенность. Иначе любая распространенная безграмотность становилась бы *как бы правильной*.

Answer (score 5):

> Но часто говорят: "Займи мне денег"

Словарями пока не фиксируется как сколько-нибудь нормативное в значении "одолжи". Но у меня впечатление, что оно рано или поздно будет "навязано" языку.
Единственное, пожалуй, препятствие - двусмысленность, поскольку "займи мне" - означает займи у кого-то третьего для меня.

Короче, на данный момент "займи мне" можно считать нормативным только в указанном значении - "займи (где-то) для меня".

Answer (score 0):

В толковом словаре Ожегова(под редакцией профессора Скворцова,2006г),в толковом словаре РАН (под редакцией Кузнецова) на Грамота.РУ,это слово дается без каких-либо помет.Смею полагать это слово давно уже стало нормативным.

Comment: «Часто говорят: "Займи мне денег". Правильно ли это?»==========  Серж, о каком слове речь? Похоже, ответ прервался неожиданно?

Comment: @shampar , речь идет о правильности варианта: занять у кого-то. вариант: займи мне - конечно неверный.

Comment: Вы пишете: «В толковом словаре Ожегова... это слово дается без каких-либо помет.» О каком слове речь?  «Вариант: займи мне» — это два слова, и о них тоже в ответе ничего не говорится. Отсюда и мой комментарий: ответ сырой.

Comment: Речь идет о слове ***занимать***.

Comment: Я не нашёл это слово в ответе — докладываю третий раз — и считаю это обманом зрения. И второе: не о слове вопрос Fuchoin Kazuki, а о выражении. И зрение тут не причём.